# Styling react-select component with CSS className in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I'm using `react-select` and I'm trying to style the Select component like written in the DOCS but adding a class with `className` does not work. The class tag is added to the DOM element's classes but doesn't affect the element itself. The theme stay the same.

If I add a class like this:

```
<Select
    className='my-class'
    {...selectProps}
/>
```

The DOM element looks like this:

```
<div class="my-class css-2b097c-container">
...
</div>
```

Which means that the default class `css-2b097c-container` of `react-select` will always "override" my custom class.
I've tried to use the `classNamePrefix` option but did not work either :(

In order to keep my UI design complete I need to design it with classes and not with inline styling!

Comment: did you try giving `!important` for your styles

Comment: @SarunUK I did think about it but it's not an ideal solution because it's not always working and not the most compatible :( thanks

Comment: Prop `className` will replace the `SelectContainer` with the className's value.
please check the style guide for more information. https://react-select.com/styles

Comment: @MuhammadHarisBaig please read my question again

Answer (score 4):

`classNamePrefix` works for most but not all components which is kinda annoying to me. Another solution is to add your own `className` as stated in your question but refer to both of them in your css using [`[attribute*=value]`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) selector to increase specificity.

```js
<Select
  className="mySelect"
  options={options}
/>
```

```css
.mySelect[class*="-container"] {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[image]

### Live Example

[image: Edit suspicious-sunset-kb6is]

Comment: Thank you very much. Though I thought it could be this way you saved my work time :)

Comment: Thank you. I shoulda looked this up about 2 hours ago... smh.